# How to store credentials for scheduled CSOM console app

Tags: sharepoint-online, timer-jobs, pnp

I am developing a console app that will be deployed as an azure webjob. The plan is to have it run daily, without user intervention.

I am using the PNP timer job framework, and according to their [guide](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/TimerJob%20Framework.md#deploying-timer-jobs-to-microsoft-azure-using-azure-webjobs), the credentials should be stored in the app.config file.

Am I wrong in thinking that this is not a secure way of dealing with credentials? If so, how can I get/store credentials securely?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store credentials in app config file.

For better security always store it in encrypted format and while consuming in program you can decrypt it.

For encryption and decryption, you can use RSA, DES algorithm etc or you can develop your own encryption and decryption algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to store credential in app.config and you can then encrypt the password like the thread below:

[Encrypt password in App.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522879/encrypt-password-in-app-config)